# gremlin query works in console but not in javascript

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, amazon-neptune

I have a query that runs fine when I run it in gremlin console but gives me an error when I put it in my javascript lambda.

```
const people = await g.V("1").out("memberOf").in("memberOf").next()
```

```
"TypeError: g.V(...).out(...).in is not a function",
```

It looks like the .in functionality is breaking.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  In Javascript, `in` is a reserved keyword.  The correct gremlin function is `in_`

Comment: Thanks for your answer that helped me, And thanks to @Kelvin, I have seen his answers all over gremlin questions :)